# Match the tags in jsoup

Tags: java, regex, string, jsoup

I want to match the tag from tag hierarchy

```
<table class='tabletext'>
    <tr align='center' style='background:#FFFFFF'>
        <td><span id='fd'><span>10</span></span></td>
        <td>10.00</td>
        <td>&pound;0.00</td>
        <td>&pound;280.00</td>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li><a href=''>ok</a></li>+
            </ul>
            <a href='/cart.php?action=add&qty=10&id=2628' title='Click here to add this item to your cart'>
                <img alt='Click here to add this item to your cart' src='/images/addtocart.gif' border='0' />
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><span>Hello2</span></td></tr>+
</table>
```

Here is my code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
            
        Elements element = doc.select(".tabletext > * > * > * > span");
        
        System.out.println(element.html());
```

Output is:

```
<span>10<span>
hello2
```

But I don't know how much tags in between `.tabletext` and `span` there are, so in that case what should be the:

```
Elements element = doc.select(".tabletext > span");
```

code for fetching above output. How to arrange `* >` for that output?

Comment: Wouldn't be better to use XPath? They are better in matching XML-based hierarchy. Regular expressions are not able to exactly cover such queries.

Comment: but it can also matching the tags and id present in tag and multiple tags in between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution

```
Elements element = doc.select(".tabletext span");
```

att att indicated the multiple tags and text in between them.

Answer (score 1):

I want to tell you that I have used `Jsoup` and stumbled into a lot of trouble when getting some info from a XML/HTML file, so I decided to use `XPath`. It is way more easier to use and you can make a lot of stuff with it.

My advice is to give it a shot:

[Parsing an XML Document with XPath](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/01/12/xpath.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you just after the 10?

You've got a parent `span` with `id='fd'`, so will this work?

```
Elements element = doc.select("#fd > span");
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply but i have .tabletext and span so how can i get the output. other tags are unknown

Comment: here is solution Elements element = doc.select("table span");

Comment: Wrong answer, an `id` is selected with `#` whereas `.`, i.e. `doc.select("#fd > span")`

Comment: But i told you that i have .tabletext and span so i want to put data in span tag which fall in the relation .tabletext span so, in that case more than one tags in between .tabletext and span but i want to put the data in the relation like .tabletext span so it works perfectly in the above scenario.

Comment: @sp00m Yeah good point mate, thanks for correcting.  Corrected my answer, but looks like I've misunderstood the question anyhow!